# Animating a logo in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, frontend

I'm trying to animate a logo in vue.js in action when you move the pointer over the logo. It should be a 'dot' of the measurements below and should move once on the action both down and up. I managed to make it appear on the bottom, but it was just blink and not smooth animation.

Here is the code I tried:

```
<circle id="Ellipse_2" data-name="Ellipse 2" cx="92.995" cy="8.495" r="3.995"  fill="#c5a075">
    <animate attributeName="cy"
        dur="3s"
        calcMode="spline"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="8.495; 52.779; 8.495"
        keySplines="0 0 1 1"
        keyTimes="0;0.5;1"/>
    </circle>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can also add a begin atttribute [`begin="mouseover"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) to your animate element.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Vue component for your logo and animation. You can do this by defining a Vue component in your JavaScript file (e.g., Logo.vue) and linking it to your HTML.

Logo.vue:

```js
<template>
  <div class="logo-container" @mouseover="animateDot">
    <div class="logo">
      <!-- Your logo SVG code goes here -->
    </div>
    <transition name="dot-animation">
      <div v-if="showDot" class="dot"></div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showDot: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    animateDot() {
      this.showDot = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showDot = false;
      }, 3000); // Adjust the duration as needed (3 seconds in this example)
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.logo-container {
  position: relative;
}

.dot-animation-enter-active,
.dot-animation-leave-active {
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out; /* Adjust the duration as needed */
}

.dot-animation-enter-to,
.dot-animation-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 8px; /* Adjust the size of your dot */
  height: 8px; /* Adjust the size of your dot */
  background-color: #c5a075;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Now you can put this anywhere you want.